# Autolayout - Modify center align with multiplier

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I want to have to buttons, which are horizontally centered in the container. Because they would overlap I want them to be a little offset from the center. I tried it with the multiplier.

If the button is in the center (as normal) the multiplier is 1. So I thought that for the left button, I specify a multiplier of 1,2 and for the right button 0,8.

And also, why is the constraint of the left button moved an the other one not?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the behavior of the multiplier for the center align constraint.  If I were doing this, I would:

1. Create a view to hold both buttons.  Drag both buttons into the new view.
2. Pin the top, left, and bottom of `TOR` to the top, left, and bottom of the new view, all with constants of 0.
3. Pin the top, right, and bottom of `STRAFE` to the top, right, and bottom of the new view, all with constants of 0.
4. Pin `TOR` to `STRAFE` with a horizontal spacing of 20.  Fix any misplaced views by updating their frames.
5. Make the new view's color **clear**.
6. Now you can click between the buttons and they will stay together.  Center their containing view horizontally and give it a vertical constraint and you're done.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This would be my next approach. But I tried to understand why auto layout is behaving like this.

Comment: I'm just not sure what it means to add a multiplier to a center constraint.  Which number are you multiplying?

Comment: Because the center align constraint has no number/constant, I am multiplying the center, which is a percental constraint.